# How to limit and orderby left join results and map them into one single field in TypeORM

Tags: database, postgresql, orm, left-join, typeorm

I have two models named **Activity** and **ActivityAttendants**. An activity can have many activity attendants (1:M). Here is my both TypeORM models

**Activity Model**

```js
export class Activity {
  @PrimaryGeneratedColumn("increment")
  activity_id!: number;

  @Column({ nullable: false })
  title!: string;

  @OneToMany(() => ActivitiyAttendant, (activity_attendants) => activity_attendants.activity, {
    cascade: true,
    onDelete: "CASCADE",
    onUpdate: "CASCADE",
  })
  @JoinColumn({ referencedColumnName: "activity_id" })
  activity_joined!: ActivitiyAttendant[];
}
```

**ActivityAttendants Model**

```js
export class ActivitiyAttendant {
  @PrimaryGeneratedColumn("increment")
  activity_attendant_id!: number;

  @Column({ comment: "joined user profile picture" })
  profile_picture!: string;

  @ManyToOne(() => Activity, (activity) => activity.activity_joined)
  @JoinColumn({ name: "activity_id" })
  activity!: Activity;
}
```

For brevity, I removed all other unnecessary fields.

Now when I do left join `ActivityAttendants` with `Activity`, I expect the output like below:

```json
[
  {
    activity_id: 2,
    title: "Sharable clear-thinking conglomeration",
    recent_attendants: [
      {
        activity_attendant_id: 2110,
        profile_picture: "1f525.svg",
      },
      {
        activity_attendant_id: 271,
        profile_picture: "1f4ce.svg",
      },
      {
        activity_attendant_id: 67,
        profile_picture: "1f525.svg",
      },
    ],
  },
  {
    activity_id: 3,
    title: "Upgradable fault-tolerant emulation",
    recent_attendants: [
      {
        activity_attendant_id: 2697,
        profile_picture: "1f469-1f3ff-200d-2764-fe0f-200d-1f48b-200d-1f468-1f3ff.svg",
      },
      {
        activity_attendant_id: 402,
        profile_picture: "1f1f9-1f1e8.svg",
      },
      {
        activity_attendant_id: 208,
        profile_picture: "1f9ef.svg",
      },
    ],
  },
];
```

Where `recent_attendants` is the array of 3(not more) most recent attendants inserted into `ActivityAttendant` (it will have a `createdAt` field for orderby) table.

Here's what I've done so far.

```js
 activityRep
  .createQueryBuilder("a")
  .leftJoinAndMapMany("a.activity_joined", "a.activity_joined", "aj")
  .select([
    "a.activity_id AS activity_id",
    "a.title AS title",
    "aj as recent_attendants",
  ])
  .getRawMany();
```

It's just doing group concat, returning one JSON for every element in the `recent_attendants` field. Moreover, it's impossible to do orderby and limit this way.

Is it possible to get expected output using TypeORM querybuilder or I have to do the data shaping programmatically?

Answer (score -3):

Okay, after running your code I *think* I understand what you're trying to do.

As I understand it, you're trying to return an object hierarchy with the sub-entity limited to always showing the latest `n` entries...

Given that, the first thing that jumps out to me is your usage of `.leftJoinAndMapMany()` in conjunction with `.select()` is not correct. You can't use those methods like that because `.select()` is for `SELECT`ing a single database column. In this instance, `aj` is an array of sub-entities returned by `.leftJoinAndSelect` at which point TypeORM turns that into a `GROUP_CONCAT()` expression.

As I see it you're probably going to have to do the data wrangling in code using `.slice()` or similar.